# Unnecessary? > "height" in TD

Tags: html, html-table

In what cases justify the "height" attr of TD over use of the "height" attribute in TR. I understand  needs to be bounded to a 2D space. And TR only has "height" because it's horizontal object concept. But TD could be qualified as a column so potentially could just be satisfied with a "width" attribute.

Sure, you can claim that TD is actually representing a table cell (w. x/y components) but a cell cannot exist w.o a table row so TD height is superfluous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case that you wanted to follow the HTML specification. Though most browsers support it, **height** was never specified as an attribute of **TR** in the W3C reference specification, but both **width** and **height** were specified as attributes of **TD** in [HTML 3.2](http://www.w3.org/TR/PR-html32-961105.html).

In any case, the width and height attributes were both deprecated for TD as of [HTML 4.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/1998/REC-html40-19980424/), and you should be using CSS anyway.

Comment: I'm using html in emails. Not sure if it supports css (outlook 2007)